# LAN issues when using wired instead of wireless

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have an issue connecting (getting timeouts) to a particular device on my network, when the client I'm trying to connect with is connected to the network over wired connection.

The moment I unplug the cable and the connection goes over wireless (not to the device directly, but over a home router, which I can connect to either way), the connection works just fine.

Any idea what this could be caused by?

The firewall on the client is not reporting any blocked connections, and is treating both connections over wireless and wired as the same network, with the same rules.

Comment: What OS is that client you're trying to connect to using? What is his IP configuration for the ethernet interface?

Comment: Windows, both WLAN and LAN are getting configured with DHCP.

Comment: Check the cable and connectors, also check the configurations of the ports, if the device is configured in half duplex and the port in the router is full duplex you will have a lot of problems due to collsions.

Comment: The link I'm getting from the client computer to the router is 100 Mbps full duplex, which is maxing out the router's capabilities.

Comment: I will check the other device once I get home.